# Passing an url as parameter to controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, parameter-passing

On my asp.net mvc page I need to render multiple images that are stored on third-party images hosting service. The service has some api which returns me a list of image urls.
In *.cshtml file a have the fallowing html markup:

```
@foreach (var img in Model.Images)
{
   <img src="@img.ImageUrl" />
}
```

It's works perfectly. But for some reason I can't use direct URL to the image in the "src" attribute. Next, I have created new async controller that should return an image:

```
public class ImagesController : AsyncController
    {
        //
        // GET: /Images/
        public void GetImageAsync(string url)
        {
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            AsyncManager.Parameters["response"] = response;
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        }

        public FileResult GetImageCompleted(WebResponse response)
        {
            return base.File(response.GetResponseStream(), response.ContentType);
        }

    }
```

Now I need to pass a full image url to my controller action.

*Something like this:*

```
@foreach (var img in Model.Images)
    {
       <img src="Images/GetImage/**@img.ImageUrl**" />
    }
```

how to create a new route for passing this parameter to action?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "GetImage",
    "Images/GetImage/{*url}",
    new { controller = "Images", action = "GetImageAsync" }
);
```

I'm not sure why you need all that though. An AsyncController + routing in order to fetch all image url's seems to be overkill...

Comment: No, not quite. For example, I have an url to image: http://example.com/Images/Image1.jpg. I need to pass this url in controller action: Images/GetImage/http://example.com/Images/Image1.jpg - of course in this form it does not work

Comment: But what what you *want* to do is just showing those images, right? You're saying you "need" to pass those urls to the async controller, but I'm saying that you don't seem to need any async controller at all. Just get all urls and render them to the view - I've done that several times, I'm sure it works. If the url's returned by that image hosting service are valid (for instance, if they work when pasted into any browser address bar), they will work in the img.src attribute...

Comment: "Images/GetImage/{*url}" - it's almost works, except one case. It's not working when i try to pass url with scheme (with "http://" or "https://"), e.g.: <img src="Images/GetImage/http:// example.com/Images/Image1.jpg" /> - not working; . I think the problem with double slash ("//").

Comment: @Ander.by: (sigh) I still don't get why you're doing it that way... But since you don't seem to be convinced, just remove the protocol + the double slash before rendering the URL. Or encode it using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and do a `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` in the async controller...

Comment: I agree with @rsenna - your making your life way too difficult. Just make a custom HTML helper which is strongly-typed to whatever `Image` is, and use a `TagBuilder` to render a `MvcHtmlString` containing the image tag. Tack on the URL as a querystring parameter. `MvcHtmlString.Create` will automatically encode it for you.